# PayPal permissions API newer integration

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-permissions

I'm integrating PayPal Permission API to access the customer's details in PayPal, But the documentation says that adaptive payment and permissions are no longer available for new integrations. Here I have shared the Documentation [link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/permissions-service/). Please suggest If any other alternative ways to integrate a permissions API

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What customer details are you looking for? If it is account profile information, [Connect with PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/connect-with-paypal/reference/#scope-attributes) can be used, with approval.

But you need to be a PayPal partner to integrate a permissions API equivalent. It will be a Connect with PayPal integration with certain specific [scopes](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/connect-with-paypal/reference/#scope-attributes) used for permissions (not the documented ones)

You need approval and guidance from PayPal in order to integrate such a new permissions API service, and for information on which specific scopes correspond to the API permission you're looking for.

A way for an account to grant permissions manually (without an API or CwPP flow) is via https://www.paypal.com/apiaccess . They need to know the classic NVP/SOAP API username of the account they'll be granting permissions to in order to do so.

Comment: To create a payment between the buyer and the seller on the seller's behalf I need  'ACCESS_BASIC_PERSONAL_DATA', 'ACCESS_ADVANCED_PERSONAL_DATA', 'DIRECT_PAYMENT', 'REFUND', 'AUTH_CAPTURE'.  datas

Comment: No, you don't -- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/pay-another-account/

Comment: Thanks Preston. For My use case buyer sends amount to seller with admin commission. Admin needs to pull out the commission from seller account without manually.